# iOS: Keyboard freezes on device but works in simulator

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

Whenever I go to enter text in a subclassed UITextfield on the device, I'll get two or three characters entered and then the app freezes. Can't dismiss the keyboard or touch any tabs. Here's the UITextField subclass:

```
@implementation OAI_TextField

@synthesize elementID;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        colorManager = [[OAI_ColorManager alloc] init];
        fileManager = [[OAI_FileManager alloc] init];

        self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0];
        self.textColor = [colorManager setColor:66.0 :66.0 :66.0];
        self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        self.delegate = self;

    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark Text Field Delegate Methods
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [self resignFirstResponder];

    //if project number text field we're going to check and see if the "Project" directory contains the file, if not we'll create it

    //get super view
    UIView* myParent = self.superview;

    //get the subviews
    NSArray* mySiblings = myParent.subviews;

    //get the label
    UILabel* myLabel = [mySiblings objectAtIndex:0];

    //get the label text
    NSString* myLabelText = myLabel.text;

    //check it!
    if ([myLabelText isEqualToString:@"Project Number:"]) {

        NSString* projectNumberPlist = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", self.text];
        NSString* projectNumberPlistPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Projects/%@", projectNumberPlist];

        [fileManager createFile:projectNumberPlist:projectNumberPlistPath];


    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"ok");
}





/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

I'll get the NSLog call in - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:. I do not get any error messages in the console. Not really sure where to begin debugging this. Could someone give me a nudge?

Thanks

Comment: OK, if I take off self.delegate and the delegate reference in the .h file it works. So what was I doing, kind of getting an endless loop by the UTF constantly referring to itself? But now that I've done that I can't get the keyboard to dismiss after I hit the "Done"/return key. Where should I be putting the delegate reference?  In the ViewController that adds the textfield as a subview?

Comment: Solved it. Massive brain fart on my part. : D